# annihilator of a family of additive subgroups ...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be $R$-module, $\left\{ K_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ be a family of additive subgroups of $M$. Prove that $ann\left(\sum_{i\in I}K_{i}\right)=\cap_{i\in I}ann\left(K_{i}\right)$ and $\sum_{i\in I}ann(K_{i})\subseteq ann(\cap_{i\in I}K_{i})$

Comment: Terminator 2 quote: "you forgot to say please...". What did you try to do? What is the exact problem you face?

Comment: I think we can reduce the problem with I={1,2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$) If $x\in ann\left(\sum_{i\in I}K_{i}\right)$ then $x\in ann K_{i}$ for all $i$ so $x\in\cap_{i\in I}ann\left(K_{i}\right)$; if $x\in\cap_{i\in I}ann\left(K_{i}\right)$ then $x\sum_{i\in I}a_i=0$ for every finite sum of elements $a_i\in K_i$ so  $x\in ann\left(\sum_{i\in I}K_{i}\right)$.

$2$) If $x\in\sum_{i\in I}ann(K_{i})$ then $x=\sum_{i\in I}x_i$, a finite sum of $x_i\in ann(K_{i})$. Therefore for every $a\in \cap_{i\in I}K_{i}$ and every $i$ we have $x_ia=0$, so $xa=0$.